# How to trace back anything that Python uses in my home dir?

Tags: python

I am running a Python script from a certain disk space. It runs for a long time on a detached terminal, but then stops, because I believe the Python script tries to do something with my homedir. My homedir is on Kereberos, so at some point the tokens expire. How can I check the python environment (which is not on the home dir) or anything else in the script to see if there are any dependencies in my home dir? I know with most certainty I am not trying to access files on the home dir *from* the script directly. It must be something in the environment.

EDIT: I am using Linux, I don't have root on the machine.

Comment: I assume some answers will depend on the operating system. Which one do you use? E.g. I would not know the details but perhaps `auditd` might work for that with some kind of rule, on ubuntu

Comment: How do you know it stops? Why do you believe it tries to do something with your homedir? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Tack on lots of logging, so you see that a logging line executed, then another line of code, followed by a logging line that definitely did not execute. With that in hand, you'll be much closer to isolating the fault.

Answer (score 1):

Use [inotifywait](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) to see such filesystem accesses.

Test it first to verify it works
with both ext4fs and AFS / Kerberos
in your environment.